# self-signed certificate SAN property

Tags: google-chrome, certificate

I want to make a self-signed certificate for my website. I make it like the link [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/) but the site is for chrome version 57 or older. So it works with chrome version 57 but not 58. I read that I need to add the SAN property for 58 or higher.

I wanted to ask where I need to add the SAN property and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it [with powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633(v=wps.630)). As stated in the documentation

> This example creates a self-signed SSL server certificate in the computer MY store with the Subject Alternative Name set to www.fabrikam.com, www.contoso.com and Subject and Issuer name set to www.fabrikam.com.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName www.fabrikam.com, www.contoso.com -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

If for some reason you need to customize the certificate more than `New-SelfSignedCertificate` can handle you can use [XCA](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/). It is built on top of OpenSSL and by default has template for SSL server. Documentation can be found [here](http://xca.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Do you know a solution how I can fix the problem with my scripts I made from the [link](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/) in the question? I want to make it like this solution because I don't have much experience in this all. Would make it much more easier for me because I know what I need to do there.

Comment: @NiZelooer [Makecert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.80).aspx) doesn't have that option.

Comment: this is really sad, so I need to use your answer but how do I do it?

Comment: @NiZelooer run the command in powershell. First DnsName value will also be Subject and issuer name (CN).

Comment: What brings me that certificate when it's not trusted? I made it like you said in your answer.

Comment: @NiZelooer Put the certificate also in the Trusted Root Authority store i.e. with certlm.msc.